# Application force close when trying to close SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a superclass for my Activities (WhereWolfActivity) in my Android app that has a static SQLiteDatabaseOpenHelper for all subclasses to use.  The database connection is opened in onCreate and closed in onDestroy (I keep track of the number of subclass Activities open to ensure the database connection is only closed when the last Activity in the app is destroyed).  When a user logs out, they are taken to a welcome screen Activity that does not subclass WhereWolfActivity, so the database connection is closed.  However, the application Force Closes when the application logs out and I get the following logcat output:

```
08-11 02:28:24.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29022): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 02:28:24.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29022): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {uk.ac.ic.doc.vmw10.wherewolf/uk.ac.ic.doc.vmw10.wherewolf.activities.Tabs}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 02:28:24.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29022):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3655)
08-11 02:28:24.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29022):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3673)
08-11 02:28:24.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29022):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2900(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-11 02:28:24.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29022):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
08-11 02:28:24.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29022):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-11 02:28:24.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29022):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-11 02:28:24.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29022):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-11 02:28:24.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29022):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 02:28:24.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29022):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-11 02:28:24.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29022):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-11 02:28:24.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29022):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-11 02:28:24.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29022):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-11 02:28:24.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29022): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 02:28:24.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29022):     at uk.ac.ic.doc.vmw10.wherewolf.activities.WhereWolfActivity.onDestroy(WhereWolfActivity.java:119)
08-11 02:28:24.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29022):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3642)
08-11 02:28:24.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29022):     ... 11 more
```

The NullPointerException occurs on the line that says: `dbHelper.close();`

Any idea why attempting to close the database would give a null pointer exception?

Comment: dbHelper may have been closed automatically when the activity is pushed into the background. BTW, why not just open connections as and when you need them?

Comment: I've seen mixed opinions on whether it's best to have 1 dbHelper for the application, or to open and close as you go, so it is this way at the moment but I don't know which design is best.

Comment: Also, the main activity of the application is a set of tabs that use cursors, and these are populated in async tasks, so I don't want to kill the database connection while they're running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't really know why without seeing your code, but apparently your `dbHelper` is null. This has nothing to do with trying to close it.

On another note, make your life simpler and have a singleton class for your database. As for closing, you don't really need to do this, just keep it open. When your process dies, that will take care of closing the database. Make sure you close all your cursors though.

Something like:

```
public class MyDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private Context context;

    private static MyDbHelper instance;

    public static MyDbHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MyDbHelper(context);
        }

        return instance;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your help.  Could you elaborate a bit on your suggestion of 'have a singleton class for your database'?

Comment: See revised post. Basically have a single instance of your database helper class accessed by all your activities, etc.

Comment: Ah I see.  I was already implementing database helper as a singleton, but taking care of it in the superclass Activity instead.  Anyway, removing the `dbHelper.close()` statement has stopped the Force Close and everything seems fine now, thanks